# OAF - How to increase the width of LOV popup screen in OAF?

Tags: oracle-ebs, oaf

I am trying to find a solution to increase the width of the LOV screen that is opened when we click on the LOV in an OAF page. Is it possbile by OAF personalization ? Or what is the corret way to increase this LOV screen width ?

RIght now since the screen width is very small, the columns values are shown up in multiple lines and so we have to scroll too much to see all the records.

Regards,
Abha

Answer (score 0):

I believe the LOV screen width is dictated by UIX (Cabo) and can't be changed via personalization.

I would take a look at the cabo JSP that is used in the popup (a.jsp or fred.jsp I think) and see if there's a hardcoded width in that.  You may be able to override that.

Of course, even if you can, that would be a customization that would need to be reapplied after UIX updates.